# Raphael JS - creating a custom progress bar

Tags: javascript, user-interface, svg, d3.js, raphael

I am trying to create a custom progress bar like in the image below:

[image: Custom progress bar]

I think my best options for creating this type of component is by using JavaScript and SVG or Canvas, and now I'm trying to create this in Raphael JS.

I was wondering if this is possible or if it's an incredible hard thing to do or maybe Raphael is not the best tool for doing this, I am pretty new to Raphael and all that I managed to do is to recreate the shapes by using Raphael JS.

```
window.onload = function() {
var paper = Raphael("holder", 500, 500);
var border = paper.path("M177.726,35.14c-6.51-19.56-24.73-30.02-46.369-35.14l-4.061,3.7c16.59,5.44,29.609,15.21,33.25,30.37c6.891,28.729-26.721,55.2-70.56,55.2c-43.84,0-77.45-26.471-70.55-55.2c3.64-15.16,16.65-24.93,33.24-30.37L48.616,0c-21.64,5.12-39.86,15.58-46.37,35.14c-12.83,38.52,31.03,74,87.74,74C146.696,109.14,190.556,73.66,177.726,35.14z M89.986,107.014c-33.546,0-64.678-13.115-79.311-33.411C2.173,61.81-0.044,48.742,4.263,35.812C9.725,19.401,24.444,8.14,48.018,2.332l0.595,0.542C31.43,9.313,20.658,19.875,17.369,33.574c-2.601,10.831,0.055,21.67,7.682,31.346c12.873,16.331,37.755,26.477,64.935,26.477c27.177,0,52.06-10.145,64.936-26.475c7.63-9.676,10.29-20.516,7.691-31.348c-3.289-13.696-14.065-24.26-31.253-30.701l0.594-0.542c23.574,5.809,38.293,17.069,43.754,33.48c4.307,12.93,2.09,25.998-6.412,37.791C154.663,93.898,123.532,107.014,89.986,107.014z");
var fill = paper.path("M173.587,33.481C168.126,17.069,153.407,5.809,129.833,0l-0.594,0.541c17.188,6.441,27.963,17.004,31.252,30.701c2.6,10.832-0.061,21.672-7.691,31.348c-12.875,16.33-37.758,26.475-64.936,26.475c-27.18,0-52.063-10.146-64.936-26.477c-7.627-9.676-10.283-20.516-7.682-31.346C18.536,17.543,29.309,6.981,46.491,0.542L45.896,0C22.322,5.809,7.603,17.069,2.142,33.48c-4.307,12.931-2.09,25.998,6.412,37.791c14.633,20.296,45.764,33.411,79.311,33.411s64.678-13.115,79.311-33.411C175.677,59.478,177.894,46.411,173.587,33.481z");

border.attr({
    fill: "#00FFFF",
});

fill.attr({
    fill: "#99FF00",
});
}
```

[JS Fiddle with shapes](http://jsfiddle.net/hexaust/ZPt9G/)

Comment: Image did not load.Do you want me to check in the Fiddle?

Comment: It loads for me. This is the link for the image [http://i.stack.imgur.com/cmGDv.png](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cmGDv.png)

Answer (score 1):

It is better you go with Canvas using KineticJS or any other API which help in order to get you quick started with the geometrical shapes and its manipulation. Since you can easily use color transitions in order to get the progress you want to see. It would be good approach if you look into Canvas rather than SVG.

Answer (score 0):

If you can break that fill into multiple pieces.. say ten pieces.

Then the first piece will be the 10 percent must up to the left.
You can then fill that one.. with whatever color you want.

Then you can fill the next one with whatever color you want.

Then instead of having a single fill-path, you have many, and you can place those paths into an array and iterate that array and fill them.

Then if you iterate to for instance, the third element and fill.. you will have filled the first three tenths of that whole progress bar.

Then off course you can split it into any arbitrary amount you can have it a hundred or whatever.

And then wrap it up with making a function called 'fill_progress_bar({"up_to":30})"
which would then for instance fill the progress bar 30 percent up.

You could also make a function 'fill_bar_portion({'number'=>3, 'with_color':'red'})', which would then for instance fill the third tenth of the progress bar with the color red. This way it would also become easy for you to fill the progress bar with whatever color combination you wanted. Not that it's not necessary but it shows the level of control you have over the progress bar by now.

Once that is setup you're basically done and never have to worry about this again.

But remember to write down the algorithm as you program for what may seem obvious now might not be so obvious in six months. Or to other developers for that matter.